NVME SSD is not detecting in Asus H97M-E motherboard
I am using Asus H97M-E motherboard with Intel i3 4thGen Processor. I went through the Asus Motherboard catalog and found it supports M.2 ( in catalog it mentioned as "The M.2 Socket 3 supports M Key and type 2260/2280 storage devices").
I recently bought WD SN350 NVMe SSD and I was able to install it in the motherboard physically without any issue.
When I start my PC the M.2 drive is not detected in BIOS. I went in Advanced mode "PCH Storage Configuration" I still do not see M.2 device instead it mentioned as "M.2 empty".
I still tried to install Win 10 pro OS using USB bootable drive, SSD drive is getting detected and I am able to format and install the files. During the windows installation at the first reboot it is taking USB as boot device since M.2 is not detected in BIOS.
Please let me know how do I make the M.2 get detected in BIOS ??
Thanks Raghu

Booting from NVMe (or any other disk type for that matter) requires firmware support. Since the motherboard is fairly old, it's entirely possible that it shipped with a BIOS lacking an NVMe driver – i.e. it might be able to boot from M.2 SATA SSDs but not M.2 NVMe ones.
(After Windows has booted, it has its own NVMe driver and doesn't rely on the firmware anymore, so it detects the disk just fine.)
The ASUS H97M-E support page shows that BIOS version 2402 adds NVMe support.

Check if the BIOS is up to date.
I'm using an Asus H97ME-plus motherboard and I updated the BIOS to 2502, the latest version available on the ASUS website for this motherboard.
Now the BIOS recognizes the installed M.2.
Watch the video in the link to configure the BIOS and install Windows on the M.2 SSD:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NGbbW6TqOvc
Good luck!
